# How do I get value of specific array element by secondary key?

Tags: php, arrays

This has to be easy but I am struggling with it. If the array below exists (named "$startersnames") and I specifically want to echo the value that has "qb" as the key, how do I do that?

I assumed $startersnames['qb'], but no luck.

$startersnames[0]['qb'] works, but I won't know that it's index 0.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qb] => Tannehill
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rb] => Ingram
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [wr] => Evans
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [wr] => Hopkins
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [wr] => Watkins
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [te] => Graham
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [pk] => Hauschka
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [def] => Rams
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [flex] => Smith
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your multi-dim array, you can loop through the outer array and test the inner array for your key.

```
function findKey(&$arr, $key) {
    foreach($arr as $innerArr){
        if(isset($innerArr[$key])) {
            return $innerArr[$key];
        }
    }
    return ""; // Not found
}

echo findKey($startersnames, "qb");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (from php 5.5) like this:

```
$qb = array_column($startersnames, 'qb');
echo $qb[0];
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/QqRuK

This approach is particularly useful when you need to print *all* the `wr` names, which are more than one. You can simply iterate like this:

```
foreach(array_column($startersnames, 'wr') as $wr) {
    echo $wr, "\n";
}
```

Comment: That's elegant as well.

Comment: Useful and elegant for filtering query results, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be expecting an array with text keys and value for each, but the array you have shown is an array of arrays: i.e. each numeric key has a value which is an array - the key/value pair where you are looking for the key 'qb'.

If you want to find a value at $array['qb'] then your array would look more like:

```
$array = [
   'qb' => 'Tannehill',
   'rb' => 'etc'
];
```

now $array['qb'] has a value.

If the array you are inspecting is a list of key/value pairs, then you have to iterate over the array members and examine each (i.e. the foreach loop shown in your first answer).

Comment: Not so. `print_r` will display an array without quotes in keys. That is what the OP has shown us. He specifically said "$startersnames[0]['qb'] works"

Comment: Indeed, print_r does strip off the quotes from strings but PHP requires the quotes around a string or a variable referencing one, generally.  Your solution works as it iterates over the array members, allowing the inner array member visibility.  The OP seemed to not observe the structure and was looking for a text key match when iterating over a numeric key, even though observing their test $starternames[0]['qb'] contained data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try foreach loop

```
$key = "qb";
foreach($startersnames as $innerArr){
    if(isset($innerArr[$key])) {
        echo $innerArr[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyNeeded = 'qb';
$indexNeeded = null;
$valueNeeded = null; 
foreach($startersnames as $index => $innerArr){
   //Compare key
   if(key($innerArray) === $keyNeeded){
      //Get value
      $valueNeeded = $innerArr[key($innerArray)];
      //Store index found
      $indexNeeded = $index;
      //Ok, I'm found, let's go!
      break;
   }
}
if(!empty($indexNeeded) && !empty($valueNeeded)){
   echo 'This is your value: ';
   echo $startersnames[$indexNeeded]['qb'];
   echo 'Or: ':
   echo $valueNeeded;  
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php